# 'Glitchy' images when rotating using bicubic interpolation

Tags: javascript, image-processing, interpolation, image-rotation

I'm working on a node.js program that to automate some image processing and right now I'm stuck with some weird result when implementing image rotation. I first tried with lineal interpolation, and I got 'jagged' results:

[image: Linear interpolation]

Then, I implemented bicubic interpolation, and I'm getting results like these:
[image: Bicubic interpolation]

I'm getting "random colored pixels" around the edge (orange means transparent), but I don't know if these artifacts are expected (I have read that some ghosting can appear) or there is a problem with my implementation.

So my question is, are those 'glitches' a flaw of the algorithm or is there a problem with my code? (I would bet for the latter) Also, I don't know much a about image processing so, am I using the right algorithm, or is there anything more suitable to my needs?

Here is my implementation, sorry for the big block of code, but I think it is easier to understand if I post eveything:

```js
var cubicInterpolation = function (x, p0, p1, p2, p3) {
    return (-0.5 * p0 + 1.5 * p1 - 1.5 * p2 + 0.5 * p3) * Math.pow(x, 3) + (p0 - 2.5 * p1 + 2 * p2 - 0.5 * p3) * Math.pow(x, 2) + (-0.5 * p0 + 0.5 * p2) * x + p1;
};

var bicubicInterpolation = function (x, y, p00, p01, p02, p03, p10, p11, p12, p13, p20, p21, p22, p23, p30, p31, p32, p33) {
    return cubicInterpolation(x, cubicInterpolation(y, p00, p01, p02, p03), cubicInterpolation(y, p10, p11, p12, p13), cubicInterpolation(y, p20, p21, p22, p23), cubicInterpolation(y, p30, p31, p32, p33));
};

//precalculate the sin and cos of the angle
var sin = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * -rotation / 360);
var cos = Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * -rotation / 360);
//the image will rotate around this point
xpivot = +(xpivot || (Math.round(frag.w / 2) + frag.x));
ypivot = +(ypivot || (Math.round(frag.h / 2) + frag.y));
//for each pixel in the ouput image (named frame)
for (var i = 0; i < +frame.$.w; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < +frame.$.h; j++) {
        //calculate the coordinates in the source image taking the pivot into ccount
        var i0 = i - xpivot + frag.x;
        var j0 = j - ypivot + frag.y;
        //calculate the rotated coordinates
        var xo = (i0 * cos - j0 * sin) + xpivot;
        var yo = (i0 * sin + j0 * cos) + ypivot;

        //get the values of the pixels in the 4x4 pixel grid around the coordinates
        var val00 = pixelValue(Math.floor(yo) - 1, Math.floor(xo) - 1, originalpng);
        var val01 = pixelValue(Math.floor(yo) - 1, Math.floor(xo), originalpng);
        var val02 = pixelValue(Math.floor(yo) - 1, Math.ceil(xo), originalpng);
        var val03 = pixelValue(Math.floor(yo) - 1, Math.ceil(xo) + 1, originalpng);

        var val10 = pixelValue(Math.floor(yo), Math.floor(xo) - 1, originalpng);
        var val11 = pixelValue(Math.floor(yo), Math.floor(xo), originalpng);
        var val12 = pixelValue(Math.floor(yo), Math.ceil(xo), originalpng);
        var val13 = pixelValue(Math.floor(yo), Math.ceil(xo) + 1, originalpng);

        var val20 = pixelValue(Math.ceil(yo), Math.floor(xo) - 1, originalpng);
        var val21 = pixelValue(Math.ceil(yo), Math.floor(xo), originalpng);
        var val22 = pixelValue(Math.ceil(yo), Math.ceil(xo), originalpng);
        var val23 = pixelValue(Math.ceil(yo), Math.ceil(xo) + 1, originalpng);

        var val30 = pixelValue(Math.ceil(yo) + 1, Math.floor(xo) - 1, originalpng);
        var val31 = pixelValue(Math.ceil(yo) + 1, Math.floor(xo), originalpng);
        var val32 = pixelValue(Math.ceil(yo) + 1, Math.ceil(xo), originalpng);
        var val33 = pixelValue(Math.ceil(yo) + 1, Math.ceil(xo) + 1, originalpng);

        //if undefined, the values should be r=g,g=0,b=0,a=0, or the neighbour pixel
        val11 = val11[0] != undefined ? val11 : [0, 0, 0, 0];
        val12 = val12[0] != undefined ? val12 : [0, 0, 0, 0];
        val21 = val21[0] != undefined ? val21 : [0, 0, 0, 0];
        val22 = val22[0] != undefined ? val22 : [0, 0, 0, 0];

        val10 = val10[0] != undefined ? val10 : val11;
        val13 = val13[0] != undefined ? val13 : val12;
        val20 = val20[0] != undefined ? val20 : val21;
        val23 = val23[0] != undefined ? val23 : val22;

        val01 = val01[0] != undefined ? val01 : val11;
        val02 = val02[0] != undefined ? val02 : val12;
        val31 = val31[0] != undefined ? val31 : val21;
        val32 = val32[0] != undefined ? val32 : val22;

        val00 = val00[0] != undefined ? val00 : val01;
        val03 = val03[0] != undefined ? val03 : val02;
        val30 = val30[0] != undefined ? val30 : val31;
        val33 = val33[0] != undefined ? val33 : val32;

        //get the x,y to fit in the bicubic interpolation
        var fx = xo - Math.floor(xo);
        var fy = yo - Math.floor(yo);

        //perform the bicubic interpolation for the alpha values
        var a = bicubicInterpolation(fx, fy, val00[3], val01[3], val02[3], val03[3], val10[3], val11[3], val12[3], val13[3], val20[3], val21[3], val22[3], val23[3], val30[3], val31[3], val32[3], val33[3]);

        //if alpha!=0 and the source coordinates are i the range wanted
        if (a != 0 && xo <= frag.w + frag.x + x && yo <= frag.h + +frag.y + y && xo >= x + frag.x && yo >= y + frag.y) {
            //perform the bicubic interpolation for the r,g,b values
            var r = bicubicInterpolation(fx, fy, val00[0], val01[0], val02[0], val03[0], val10[0], val11[0], val12[0], val13[0], val20[0], val21[0], val22[0], val23[0], val30[0], val31[0], val32[0], val33[0]);
            var g = bicubicInterpolation(fx, fy, val00[1], val01[1], val02[1], val03[1], val10[1], val11[1], val12[1], val13[1], val20[1], val21[1], val22[1], val23[1], val30[1], val31[1], val32[1], val33[1]);
            var b = bicubicInterpolation(fx, fy, val00[2], val01[2], val02[2], val03[2], val10[2], val11[2], val12[2], val13[2], val20[2], val21[2], val22[2], val23[2], val30[2], val31[2], val32[2], val33[2]);
            //draw the pixel
            paintPixel(+frame.$.x + i, +frame.$.y + j, Math.round(r), Math.round(g), Math.round(b), Math.round(a * alpha));
            //console.log(Math.round(r), Math.round(g), Math.round(b), Math.round(a * alpha));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to say that for smaller images there will be no satisfactory algorithms.  I'd suggest you process much larger images, then scale them down to the size you need.

Comment: Is that what programs such as Adobe Photoshop do? I'm worried about the extra processing time that it will need, I would like to process big batches of files.

Comment: Having used photoshop in my time, and having seen the pixels, I can attest that PS does a good job with their algorithms re not introducing many artifacts.  They do ***pay*** for this, you know, by employing experts in image processing.  Think of the triangle--cheap, fast, correct. You get to pick two. I'd suggest you go with cheap and correct, and process larger images (find the smallest size which produces the best results!).